# Mysql regroup results if one column result in common

Tags: php, mysql, join

I'm currently using 1-inf request in MySQL and I have a little problem right now.

Is it possible to join, concat, regroup some results who has the same column result in common ?

This are my ouptut

[image]

You have lessons (column one) who can be teach by teachers (column two) and the class (column three).

Is there a way to join them and have a result like

cours | professeurs1 professeurs2 professeurs3 | classe

Here is my query:

```
SELECT cours.cours, professeurs.nom, classe.classe
FROM cours
JOIN classe
    ON cours.id_classe = classe.id
JOIN cours_professeurs
    ON cours_professeurs.id_cours = cours.id
JOIN professeurs
    ON cours_professeurs.id_prof = professeurs.id
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use GROUP_CONCAT and you will have to use group by with it too.

```
SELECT 
    cours.cours, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(professeurs.nom) AS teachers, 
    classe.classe
FROM cours
JOIN classe
    ON cours.id_classe = classe.id
JOIN cours_professeurs
    ON cours_professeurs.id_cours = cours.id
JOIN professeurs
    ON cours_professeurs.id_prof = professeurs.id
GROUP BY cours.cours,classe.classe
```

Comment: You need to group by both: `GROUP BY cours.cours, classe.classe`

Comment: @ypercube well! it does not matter in this situation the results will be same!

Comment: Not with the sample data above but you don't except the `classe` column to have identical data, do you?

Comment: No, I just want to have classes if they are different. If it's identical, I just need one record of the classe.

Comment: I used GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT) for have it :) It remove duplicates values :)

Comment: Well if you had mention it i would do it instead of you. Glad you found yourself. Cheers!

Answer (score -4):

Yes, you can do this using the GROUP BY() MySQL statement.